# Add leading zero to numbers between special tags

Tags: bash, shell, sed, xmlstarlet

I know it is not complicated to add leading zero to numbers. However, I am looking for an optimal solution to add leading zero only to values between `<SpecialTag>0</SpecialTag>` to make them 5 digits.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes" ?>
<Root>
    <Row>
        <Tag1>0</Tag1>
        <SpecialTag>0</SpecialTag>
        <Tag2>0</Tag2>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Tag1>0</Tag1>
        <SpecialTag>12</SpecialTag>
        <Tag2>0</Tag2>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Tag1>0</Tag1>
        <SpecialTag>12345</SpecialTag>
        <Tag2>0</Tag2>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Tag1>0</Tag1>
        <SpecialTag>1234</SpecialTag>
        <Tag2>0</Tag2>
    </Row>
</Root>
```

Expected results should be like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes" ?>
<Root>
    <Row>
        <Tag1>0</Tag1>
        <SpecialTag>00000</SpecialTag>
        <Tag2>0</Tag2>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Tag1>0</Tag1>
        <SpecialTag>00012</SpecialTag>
        <Tag2>0</Tag2>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Tag1>0</Tag1>
        <SpecialTag>12345</SpecialTag>
        <Tag2>0</Tag2>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Tag1>0</Tag1>
        <SpecialTag>01234</SpecialTag>
        <Tag2>0</Tag2>
    </Row>
</Root>
```

Comment: IMHO experts always advice not to parse xml files with `sed` or `awk`, ion spite of them use tools which are meant of parsing them like `xmlstarlet` I am adding that tag here now.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 totally agree with you but I could not manage using `xmlstarlet` and `xmllint`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Using *xsltproc* (**Suggested solution!**):

Having XLST file `transform.xsl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Matches the SpecialTag -->
    <xsl:template match="SpecialTag">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- The number is available using node() and format-number() applies the 0-padding -->
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(node(), '00000')" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Run the following, provided that `input.xml` contains your XML:

```
$ xsltproc transform.xml input.xml
```

## Unsafe solutions:

Those rely on the fact that opening tag `<SpecialTag>` and closing tag `</SpecialTag>` are on the same line and that there is only one of them per line.

The solutions below are **only** mentioned because the author explicitly tagged the question with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)/[bash](/questions/tagged/bash)/[shell](/questions/tagged/shell). Those are **not the right tools to achieve the job**!

They all work with regular expressions to catch `<SpecialTag>`, followed by several numbers then `</SpecialTag>` and transform the numbers caught with a 0-padded version of those numbers.

### Using *sed*:

```
sed --regexp-extended 's@<SpecialTag>([0-9]+)</SpecialTag>@<SpecialTag>0000000\1</SpecialTag>@;s@0*([0-9]{5,})@\1@'
```

### Using *perl*:

```
perl -pe 's@<SpecialTag>([0-9]+)</SpecialTag>@sprintf("<SpecialTag>%05d</SpecialTag>",$1)@e'
```

### Using *awk*:

```
awk '{gsub( /<SpecialTag>[0-9]+<\/SpecialTag>/, sprintf("<SpecialTag>%05d</SpecialTag>", gensub(/[^0-9]/, "","g"))); print}'
```

Comment: Many thanks for your proposals and advice. I highly appreciate if you write short explanation.

Comment: Once again thanks for the details. Any idea how to resolve if there are other tags on the same line together with the SpecialTag using `sed`? It is because I have multiple xml documents combined into one, therefore, I cannot use `xsltproc` because it cannot parse the file.

Comment: Yes: Avoid sed/perl/awk at all price and use an XML parser, like the suggested xsltproc answer. You may ask how to put a screw in a wall with a hammer. An answer to your *question* would indeed involve a hammer, but an answer to your *problem* would definitely suggest a screwdriver.

Comment: I agree with you but unfortunately I am dealing with a file that is a combination of multiple xml documents, therefore, tools such as `xmlstarlet`, `xmllint` and `xsltproc` cannot parse it.

Comment: I would suggest an intermediate step that would enable the extraction of individual XML files.

Comment: If each concatenated section is valid xml then you could wrap it in a container section <outer>...file content...</outer>, parse that, and then remove the outer tag. As the parser should not change the whitespace the removal could be dumb.